my LyX header is not long enough
im new to LyX. I'm trying adding a header to the page and it seems too short, i would prefer if its longer but i don't know how to do, please help me.

This is my code, sorry everyone because this is my first time using this website :((
\documentclass[12pt,vietnamese]{article}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Temp}

\maketitle
\newpage{}

\lhead{onetwothree}

\chead{ssdfsdfsd}

\rfoot{fsdfsdfsdfsdfs}

\section{abcdef}

asdasdasda

dasdasda

dasdasdasd

asdasdasdasda

dasdads
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! How do you think we can help without seeing no TeX code in your question? Please add a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue!

To add, please copy the lyx-file into your question AND mark it as code (it's just a plain-text file), OR swith to the Code Preview Pane and copy the LaTeX code found there. The lyx-file is prefered, as the Code preview changes from lyx-activities.

LyX user questions on TeX stackexchange can help you asking good LyX questions. Without, I would guess, that you are using a manually added LaTeX preamble, that changes the page margins after setting up the page header using fancyhdr. Loading fancyhdr after all changes of the margins, but not before, usually helps in such cases.

im so sorry everyone, this is my first time using stack exchange, i added the code right above

@LonggNguyễn: I’ve added code tags to make your example code format correctly.  To clarify, what do you mean by wanting the header “longer”?  Do you mean you want more vertical spacing between the header and the body text?

Do you mean you want to make the header wider to match the paragraph below?

yes sir, i want the header to be wider, i exported it to .tex file, then i open it with texworks and edited by bringing the
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
after the margins code then it worked but how can i change the order of code in LyX ?

In your MWE it is enough to set the margins with geometry before loading fancyhdr and setting the fancy style. Otherwise, fancyhdr will make the header according to the default margins. If you make this change and add some dummy text to reveal the right margin, the result should be:

To load both packages in LyX in the right order,  do not use the LateX Preamble, but Documents → Settings ... →Page Margins for the first, and for the second, Modules → Page Layout → Custom Header/Footer Text and then select the fancy style in Page Layout option.
Then check in View → Code Preview Pane that the packages are already loaded in the right order. Only then, and only if the default header and footer are not what you want, use the LateX Preamble to add the fancyhdr macros (\lhead{}, etc.) but without duplicating the code already added by LyX.

Try inserting the line
\headwidth=\textwidth

into the preamble of your LyX document. (Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble).
LyX processes these user-specified commands last, so it should end up with the correct header width.

